# Multiple Select in Single Query but more than one distinct field name

Tags: mysql, vb.net, select, datatable, multiple-select

When there is multiple Fieldname (Turnover and NetProfit) in the select statement below, error is occured when I fill the mySqlDataAdapter to datatable. I will then put it into datagridview. how to fix it?

Data:

```sql
FieldName | Ticker| Value| Year
--
Turnover  | APPL  | 1555 | 2010
Turnover  | APPL  | 1688 | 2011 
Turnover  | APPL  | 1900 | 2012
Turnover  | APPL  | 1989 | 2013 
NetProfit | APPL  | 123  | 2010
NetProfit | APPL  | 158  | 2011 
NetProfit | APPL  | 200  | 2012
NetProfit | APPL  | 300  | 2013
```

Code:

```vb
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, cn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt) 'error occurred here!!! if more than 1 distinct fieldname
dgv1.DataSource = dt
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT 
 (SELECT format(Value,0) from Data WHERE Ticker = 'APPL' AND Year = 2010) As 'Y2010' ,
 (SELECT format(Value,0) from Data WHERE Ticker = 'APPL' AND Year = 2011) As 'Y2011' ,
 (SELECT format(Value,0) from Data WHERE Ticker = 'APPL' AND Year = 2012) As 'Y2012' ,
 (SELECT format(Value,0) from Data WHERE Ticker = 'APPL' AND Year = 2013) As 'Y2013'
```

Output: (NO Net profit in the DATA table)
(If the Data table only contains one FieldName, say Turnover, so below the output is for turnover)

```sql
Y2010| Y2011| Y2012| Y2013
--
1555 | 1688 | 1900 | 1989
```

Output: (2 fieldnames in Data table i.e. turnover and Net Profit

(not successful)

My Desired Output: (as currently, I have add a criteria "WHERE Ticker = ")

```sql
FieldName | Y2010 | Y2011 | Y2012 | Y2013
--
Turnover  | 1555  | 1688  | 1900  | 1989
NetProfit | 123   | 158   | 200   | 300
```

Next Step Desired Output: (for all tickers)

```sql
Ticker| FieldName | Y2010| Y2011| Y2012| Y2013
--
APPL  | Turnover  | 1555 | 1688 | 1900 | 1989
APPL  | NetProfit | 123  | 158  | 200  | 300
MSFT  | Turnover  | 2555 | 2688 | 1600 | 3489
MSFT  | NetProfit | 133  | 248  | 205  | 300
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the error?

Comment: I also don't see your SQL you are trying to run. Both of these things are kind of important to be able to help.

Comment: my SQL is on the above Query. It works fine only when I have designated the Ticker, and there is only one fieldname, either turnover or netprofit, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the desired result

```sql
select distinct 
cast(data.Ticker as char(20)), 
cast(data.FieldName as char(20)),
d2010.Value as 'Y2010' ,
d2011.Value as 'Y2011' ,
d2012.Value as 'Y2012' ,
d2013.Value as 'Y2013' 
from data
inner join data as d2010 on data.FieldName like d2010.FieldName and d2010.Year = 2010
inner join data as d2011 on data.FieldName like d2011.FieldName and d2011.Year = 2011
inner join data as d2012 on data.FieldName like d2012.FieldName and d2012.Year = 2012
inner join data as d2013 on data.FieldName like d2013.FieldName and d2013.Year = 2013
```

Note: The cast is required for `distinct` if the text fields are Text type. I tested this in MSSQL and checked syntax in a MySQL validator.